# XML Custom serialization

Tags: xml, vb.net, xml-serialization, xml-parsing, xsd

I get this xml string from a web service that I can't control:

```
<foo>
   <BIRTHTIME>02.06.2012-01:34.41 1338593681</BIRTHTIME>
</foo>
```

Currently, I deserialize the above xml string into this class:

```
Public Class AppData
    Public BIRTHTIME As String
End class
```

As you can see AppData.BIRTHTIME is a string data type, but it needs to be a date data type. What I would like to accomplish is deserialize the xml string into this class:

```
Public Class AppData
    Public BIRTHTIME As Date
End class
```

The problem is that when I deserialize the xml into the above class, I get this error "Input string was not in a correct format." . Can somebody provide an elegant solution to solve this problem? Thx

Comment: What's the *1338593681* about? Does it have any meaning for your DateTime value?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the IXmlSerializable interface and parse out the property yourself because it is malformed.

Check out this page for more information about implementation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can control de-serializing by using a property that is ignored when (de-)serializing.

Since it's not clear what the last numeric part of your source date string represents my example doesn't deal with it - you may need to extend the according getter and setter logic.

```
Public Class AppData
    Private birthdatetime As DateTime
    Private birthtimestring As String


    <XmlElement(ElementName := "BIRTHTIME")>
    Public Property DateString As String
        Get
            Return String.Format("{0:dd.MM.yyyy-HH:mm:ss} 1338593681", birthdatetime);
        End Get

        Set
            birthtimestring = Value
            Dim datetimepart As String() = birthtimestring.Split(New [Char]() {" "c})(0)
            Dim ci As New CultureInfo("de-DE")
            DateTime.TryParseExact(datetimepart, "dd.MM.yyyy-HH:mm:ss", ci, DateTimeStyles.None, birthdatetime)
        End Set
    End Property


    <XmlIgnore()>
    Public Property BirthDate As DateTime
        Get
            Return birthdatetime
        End Get

        Set
            birthdatetime = Value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

*Disclaimer: I'm not really proficient with VB.Net so my example translated from C# may contain some errors. Feel free to edit out any mistakes*